# how to find the outline of union rectangles

Tags: python, opencv

I have coordinates of each rectangles and want to find the outlines of union rectangles.
[image: rectangles]

[image: outline of rectangles]

So what I did is that just drew and colored all rectangles with the coordinates.
And found the contour of all rectangles.
[image: colored rectangles]

But I want to know that if there are some kind of algorithms
doing the same thing only with coordinates information.
So that I don't need to draw and color the whole rectangles.
(there are more than 4000 rectangles so it is computationally expensive)

Comment: Are the rectangles' edges always vertical? Are the rectangles always black lines on a white image?

Comment: @kevinkayaks Thanks for answering. yes, the edges always vertical. I only have coordinates of each rectangles, so unless I draw them there is no color.

Comment: I think your method seems smart.. Are you drawing the coordinates with a for loop or with masking?

Comment: @kevinkayaks Now I am drawing those with a for loop. Because I am obtaining the coordinates of rectangles from the for loop. Should I just take the coordinates from the for loop into a list and mask it all after the for loop ?

Comment: Yes I think it'd be much faster if you collated the coordinates into a `2XN` numpy array where `N` is the number of points, then you modified the entire image at once like `im[coordinates]=0.0`, where `im = np.ones(shape)`. Then you can use `findcontours` from `cv2` as suggested in the answers by others below

Comment: @kevinkayaks Thanks for reminding me about masking. I already have used "findContours" for the ways mentioned in the question. What I really wanted to know was that solving the problem without using computer vision techniques (drawing, finding contours), but manipulating coordinates using some kind of algorithms. Anyways, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share a list of a few more coordinates and the corresponding image for testing some ideas please? Also, consider splitting the 4,000 rectangles across say 4 threads and letting each thread draw 1,000 rectangles on its own blank background then compositing the 4 results together.

Answer (score 0):

Using contour detection you can achieve what you want. For that you should have a good knowledge about contour hierarchy style used in OpenCV. There are a few contour retrieval modes. Such as `cv2.RETR_LIST`, `cv2.RETR_TREE`, `cv2.RETR_CCOMP`, `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) for more information.

In your case you should use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` in order to retrieve extreme outer contour of the image.

This is the solution code:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.bitwise_not(imgray,imgray)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("image", im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`findContours` is the function you are looking for. The code bellow explains how it works.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread("./outline_rect.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh = 255-thresh
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


maxArea = 0
best = None
for contour in cnts:
  area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
  if area > maxArea :
    maxArea = area
    best = contour

cv2.drawContours(img, [best], 0, (0, 0, 255), 3)

while True:
  cv2.imshow("result", img)
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
      break
```

The result:
[image: result of the code]